# Detecting if the form field values have been modified

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I have a multi-step form which asks the subscriber to check their details before proceeding with the renewal process.

What I want to do is check if the form has been modified from its pre-filled values (extracted from a Web Service) and then write it to my own local MySQL database.  This should only happen if the values have been modified from the original.

I know I can do this by using the == operator but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with (multidimensional) arrays. Name the form/service variables carefully then compare them upon submit with [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which tells you which values has been modified.
Because you said this is a multi-step form, of course you can collect previously submitted values in a `$_SESSION` variable too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript on client side:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="username">
```

**Javascript**

```
var input = $('#username');
if (input.defaultValue != input.value) {
    //Do stuff if different 
} else {
    //Do stuff if equal
}
```

Comment: This can be tricked (if the client has disabled JS) or would be heavy if the form is big or (as the OP stated) the form is multi-step.